# How can we get the same output in c++?

Tags: python, c++, for-loop

I'm new to c++ and recently shifted from python. Can anyone explain me what should be the actual code in c++, if we want to print items of a list in for loop.
For example: in python. We do something like.

```py
sample_list = ['you', 'are','awesome']
for i in sample_list:
    print(i)
```

In C++ its something like.

```
for(initialisation, condition, updation )
{ 
Your code
}
```

But there is no update We just want to get items from a list.

How can I do same in C++?

Comment: You can iterate through a vector using the index but maybe you want a range based for loop. See the example at the bottom: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: I want a for loop. Which print all the values of a list until last item comes.

Comment: `for i in sample_list:` -> `for(const auto &i : sample_list)`

Comment: Where is your `C++` code? Do you already have a collection? Have you looked up the different `for` loops in `C++`?

Comment: *For example: in python. We do something like.* -- What Python does is really irrelevant.  You are now coding in C++.  Even your comment that you want a "for loop"  is a bad sign that you are attempting to use Python as a model in writing C++ code.  Don't do that.

Comment: If you want to learn C++ then please invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < sample_list.size(); i++){
    cout << sample_list[i] << "\n";
}
```

or

```
for(auto i : sample_list) {
    cout << i << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the form `for(:)` to iterate over every list element.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{   
    std::vector<std::string> sample_list{"you", "are", "awesome"};

    for (auto item : sample_list)
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for a string array made with

```
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string array[];
}
```

Now all you need to do is run a for loop that prints the Ith member of the array with

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string array[5];
  for(int i; i<5; i++) {
    std::cout << array[i] << std::endl;
  }
}
```